# How can I show the average percatage of this some colums in highcharts?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

[image]

Currently when I hover on the column show 100%.

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: {series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.0f}'
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new with asking questions and the image is on the: "enter image description here" link

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: The problem is solved I used pointFormatter: function () {..that calculates the total of the  Y's and then returning this.Y/TOTAL   }